# How does GHC interpret `foldl + 0 [1,2,3]` (without parentheses around +)?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

One thing that got me stuck early when learning Haskell was the difference between `foldl +` and `foldl (+)`.

```
Prelude> :t foldl + 0 [1,2,3]
  :: (Num t1, Num ((b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b),
      Num ([t1] -> (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b), Foldable t) =>
     (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

vs

```
Prelude> :t foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] :: Num b => b
```

How does Haskell / GHC derive the type of `foldl + 0 [1,2,3]`? How can I understand why it expands to this giant type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `+` is an infix operator and there are no parentheses overriding things,

```
foldl + 0 [1,2,3]
```

parses as

```
(foldl) + (0 [1,2,3])
```

The easiest starting point is the type of `foldl`, which is well known (and if you don't know it, you can just ask GHCI with `:t foldl`).

```
foldl :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a
```

Next, the other side of the addition. Because `0` is being applied as a function with `[1,2,3]` as an argument, there must be a Num instance for a function type which takes a list of some numeric type as input, and produces as output...well, we'll get to that.

```
0 [1,2,3] :: (Num t, Num ([t] -> s)) => s
```

Because `+` is being applied to these two expressions, they must have the same type. Therefore, we must unify

```
foldl :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a
```

with

```
0 [1,2,3] :: (Num t, Num ([t] -> s)) => s
```

The most general way to do that is to let `s` be the exact same type as `foldl` (combining their constraints), giving us

```
0 [1,2,3] :: (Foldable f,
              Num t, 
              Num ([t] -> (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a)) 
          => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a
```

And remember that of course `foldl` must have precisely the same type:

```
foldl :: (Foldable f, 
          Num t,
          Num ([t] -> (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a)) 
      => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a
```

And since `+` is from the Num typeclass, the type that they share must be Num as well.

```
foldl + 0 [1,2,3] :: (Foldable f, 
                      Num t, 
                      Num ([t] -> (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a),
                      Num ((a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a))
                  => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a
```

Which as you can see is, modulo some renaming of types, just what GHC told you.

But of course, this is a rather silly type. It's *possible* someone would write all these outrageous Num instances, so GHC dutifully infers this as a valid type. But nobody actually has written these instances, so you will have a great deal of trouble actually using this expression. Really what you should do is fix your parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

`foldl + 0 [1,2,3]` is parsed as the sum of `foldl` and `0 [1,2,3]`, which is `0` applied to the list `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell parentheses are not only used to set precedence of expression evaluation. The two statements are actually quite different.

The sign + is an *operator*, so it's supposed to work like `a + b = c`. That is, one function argument to the left and the other to the right. You say the operator is used in *infix* notation when it is like that.

You can covert any operator to a normal function being in the *prefix* notation by having parentheses. `(+) a b = c`.

Because of this, your two provided expressions are quite different. It's natural they have different type signatures.